# Proving equality related to Laurent series and integration

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, laurent-series

Here's a question that really makes me confused and I don't even know how to start solving it.

Let $\sum a_n(z-a)^n$ define a Laurent series expansion that converges uniformly to a function $f$ in the disk $D(a,r),r>0$. Show that: 
$$\sum\vert a_n \vert^2 r^{2n} = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} \vert f(a+r e^{i \theta}) \vert ^2 d\theta <[M(r)]^2$$

such that $M(r)=sup_{z \in D(a,r)} \vert f(z) \vert$

How can I start solving the problem?

Comment: There is an $=$ and a $<$.  Can you do one of them?

Comment: I think I can do < , but I`m totally confused about =

Comment: It isn't worth calling the series a *Laurent* series since we're only accepting $n\geq 0$. Remember that an arbitrary Laurent series admits $n\leq -1$. Having said that... Regarding the $=$... You could try substituting the power series expansion directly into the integral and see what happens. Using $z\bar z=|z|^2$, of course. If such sugestion doesn't please you (which is totally fine) you could try using [Parseval's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_identity).

Comment: well, you are right that I need to use Laurent series actually from $- \infty $ to $ \infty $. However, I still don`t know how to use all these information together to get the result.